# mongodb aggregation pipeline, fold an array property in `$project`ion

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Given a collection of documents that each has an array property `ks`:

```json
{
  _id: ObjectId('...'),
  ks: [4, 3, 2, 1, 3], 
  v: 45
},
{
  _id: ObjectId('...'),
  ks: [3, 3, 5], 
  v: 21
},
{
  _id: ObjectId('...'),
  ks: [1, 5, 2, 8, 9, 7],
  v: 12
}
```

How can I aggregate this collection to a list using `key = min ks` or other fold functions?

```json
[
    {
        _id: 1,
        v: 28.5 // = mean [45, 12]
    },
    {
        _id: 3,
        v: 21 // = mean [21]
    }
]
```

Grouping using  the `keyf` [function](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.group/) works

```
keyf: function(d) { d.ks.reduce(function(acc, a) { return acc<a ? acc : a; }) }
```

But is there a way to do this with aggregation pipeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you want the minimum [**`$min`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/min/) value of `ks` for your aggregation key and the [**`$avg`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/avg/) of "v" for each `min ks`. You need to [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) "ks" first.

You also need to [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) your data twice, once for finding the `min` of `ks` and the next time for calculating the `avg` of `v`.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    // Unwind the array
    { "$unwind": "$ks" },

    // Find the minimal key per document
    { "$group": {
         "_id": "$_id",
         "ks": { "$min": "$ks" },
         "v": { "$first": "$v" }
    }},

    // Group with the average value
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$ks",
        "v": { "$avg": "$v" }
    }},

    // Group does not sort results
    { "$sort": { "_id": 1 } }
])
```

Results in:

```js
[ 
    { 
        "_id" : 1, 
        "v" : 28.5 
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : 3, 
        "v" : 21 
    } 
]
```